# Magento inline translation doesn't work for each text block

Tags: magento, translation

I cannot translate each block with magento inline translation tool, some of them can be, but some cannot.

I have found that inline translation doesn't work for text placed in div elements (wtf ?), and solution is to wrap text with span. I did so, but i still cannot make this text translated with inline tool. I have even changed wrapping div to span - still not able to translate it.

Have somebody some advices how to make it work correctly ?

Comment: What about showing us your code? From your current description I understood that you are trying to transalte html tags (wtf?).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your source text is not longer than 255 characters